# AS3 POST return value '+' been removed

Tags: actionscript-3

when i do a post with flash and it return variable, however all the '+' sybomle within the string been removed? Anyone know how to avoid that?

```
private function roomPostCompleteHandler(e:Event):void{
     var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
}
```

Comment: i work it out if use URLVariables flash will just remove all the '+' symbol but if you use loader.data, they remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'+' is the shorthand for '%20' (percent-encoded space character), so, for once URLVariables is doing it right - it may not remove it, as you say, but replace it with the space character. So, whatever `e.target.data` is, if you expect it to send the '+' character (not the space), it should be '%28'.

Comment: Thanks totally understand now